# Am I using the NEW context API or am I using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have learn React and I have learn to use the Context API, but I heard that there is a "new context api" and since i've learned React with a kind of old course (late 2017), I don't know if i'm using the new or old Context API.
Also i've just discovered Redux and it looks barely exactly like what I am using, so is Redux and the Context API the same in the end ?

Look at my code :

Here my context.js :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

const Context = React.createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'DELETE_CONTACT' :
        return {
            ...state,
            contacts: state.contacts.filter(contact => 
                contact.id !== action.payload)
        };
        default: 
        return state;
    }

}

export class Provider extends Component {
    state = {
        contacts : [
            {
                id: 1,
                nom : 'John Doe',
                email : 'john@gmail.com',
                tel : "555-555-5555"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                nom : 'John Doe',
                email : 'john@gmail.com',
                tel : "555-555-5555"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                nom : 'Hugo Doe',
                email : 'john@gmail.com',
                tel : "555-555-5555"
            }
        ],
        dispatch: action => {
            this.setState(state => reducer(state,action))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{
                state: this.state,
                sayHello: () => console.log("Hello World")

            }}>
            {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

Note that i'm using a "Reducer" and a "Dispatch" which are not even in the React oficial documentation for "Context" :( ?

Also you can look at my "consumer" :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Contact from './Contact'
import {Consumer} from '../context'

export default class Liste extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
          return(
            <React.Fragment>
            {value.state.contacts.map(contact => (
                <Contact 
                key={contact.id}
                id={contact.id}
                nom={contact.nom}
                email={contact.email}
                tel={contact.tel}
                />
            ))}
          </React.Fragment>
          )
        }}
      </Consumer>
    )
  }


}
```

What are the concrete differences between Context and React ?
Am I allowed to use Reducer with Context ?
Am I using the Old or New Context ?
Why Context is good for little app and Redux for big App ?

So many questions I can't clearly respond to, there is a ton of articles and videos who are saying exactly the opposite.

Can someone have the kindness to enlight me ?

Answer (score 1):

From the examples above it does not look like you are using Redux at all.

React's Context API and Redux are similar in that both are methods of passing data through the component tree without having to pass props manually at every level.

Since React's Context API with Hooks wasn't in production until React ~v16.8, Redux was the only option to pass the data. Now with the Context API and hooks, my prediction is that you will see Redux fade off into the sunset. However, I should make the note that when implemented poorly, the Context API can quickly become a headache when a section of your applications requires a number of different Contexts.

Here is a little application that I built when studying React context and hooks that might help you get a better grasp on them:

https://github.com/Borduhh/react-hooks-context-example

Comment: Just updated the project as well to include detailed notes about what is going on as well as links to more information about those particular subjects.

Answer (score 1):

React Redux and the Context API are not the same thing. Context is an easy way to pass data down through nested child components without smuggling them through every child prop on the way down.

The Context API is not a state manager like Redux. It can be used as one, but it's best to pass data ( like styles or auth ) not mutate/change it. Context uses a provider tag + render props to pass data. when the context data changes, everything ( all the child elements ) inside the provider tag get re-rendered. So if you have your entire app or a large amount of it wrapped in a provider you may want to check your re-renderings.

Redux is a state manager and is used when you have large amounts of state ( your call on the definition of large ). Its slightly complex to set up, but you get a very powerful mature third party library for managing state. It has great dev tools and is very efficient when set up right.

The Hooks API has opened up new doors in state management. In my opinion, its the middle ground before redux.

check out this repo useContext + useReducer + independent re-renders:

Context Provider Wrapper Example: https://github.com/joha0033/race-series-2/blob/master/src/Context/Authorization/authorization.js

Using Context Wrapper Example: https://github.com/joha0033/race-series-2/blob/master/src/App.js

I would look into getting used to hooks and how they play a role in new managing your application's state.

The Context API you are currently using should be the latest. The newest React update ( with hooks ) included a hook called useContext. this hook does not change the way you create or provide context, but it makes it simpler to consume it in components that depend on the context.

Here's some resources of mine:

https://testdriven.io/blog/react-hooks-primer/

https://testdriven.io/blog/react-hooks-advanced/

Comment: Hey thank's for that response, it helped me a bit, I have one more and I should be all right.
I can't see any reducers or dispatch or action in the react context documentation :
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
So, where my instructor did find this ?
When i'm typing "context reducers" or "context dispatch" I can't find anything related on Google.